# How to Send numerous analog signals from 1 source, separately to entities

Tags: signals, signal-processing, microcontroller, mbed

On the mbed FRDM board, there is only 1 or 2 analog_out's that I am aware of, however I need to be able to independently power up to 4-5 separate motors ( as in i want to be able to say ONLY turn on motor 3 without turning on motor 2 or 1). If I was to join them upon 1 cable, then all would activate at the same time, but this seems to be the only way as there is only 1 output (please tell me if there are more, i am very new to this). How could I send multiple signals through the same wire and have them power independently the motors?

Comment: It's absolutely unclear: what motors you have? And what do you mean by "outlet" word? As I see, your board have many GPIO outputs (they can only turns on or off) and many PWMs (can be used to smooth control of motors).

Comment: Sorry, by outlet I meant output ( as in a socket/pin area). However, despite that I am very new, I can't see how the type of motor would affect the solution, as it is the core concept behind it would be the same for any component same (besides power usage). (it's a tiny hobby electronically wired motor if you did need to know)